# How to generate a pyramid of words in python based on a dictionary of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I want to generate a pyramid using Python that has the following structure:

The pyramid is built using the following:

The user enters an integer between 1 and 15. Then a "word pyramid" of the requested height is generated. A "word pyramid" is a string of multiple lines, starting with a word of length 1 (first line), followed by a word of length 2(second line), followed by a word of length 3, etc. up to a word with a length that is the height of the pyramid.

Each next word has the same letters as the previous word (though not necessarily in the same order) with one extra letter added.

The pyramid of length 5 looks like so:

```
    a
    ad
    tad
    date
    tread
```

The words are taken from a list of English words (so there are enough words for any given size of the pyramid in order to complete the pyramid).

I have tried the following:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
alphabet = ascii_lowercase




def finding(word,target):
    chars = []
    temp_chars = []

    for char in word:
        chars.append(char)


    for char in target:
        temp_chars.append(char)
    ok=0


    for char in chars:
        if temp_chars.count(char) >= 1:
            ok += 1


    if ok != len(word):
        return False
        exit()
    else:
        if len(target) == len(word) +1:
            print("For word", target)
            return True
            exit()
        else:
            return False
            exit()





def game():
    outcome = ""
    fp = open("wordsEn.txt")
    contents = fp.read()
    words = contents.split(" ")

    user_input = input("Give num from 1 to 15")
    num = int(user_input)

    if outcome ==  "" :
        my_choice = choice(list(alphabet))
        outcome += my_choice + "\n"
        line = my_choice



    for word in words:
        if len(line) > num:
            return outcome
            exit()
        else:
            if finding(line,word):
                line = word
                outcome += line + "\n" 


print(game())
```

The first "finding" function works, and it finds the next word that would fill the next line for the pyramid. I have tried the code for a small list of a few words, and although the outcome string (which is a string that stores the pyramid) had the right form, nevertheless I have the "None" output, both in the small example and in the large example with all the English words.

Comment: Can you share the file "wordsEn.txt"? (if it isn't big, for example on pastebin)

Comment: The file I mentioned is within a platform and I do not know exactly how to access it, but here https://github.com/dwyl/english-words  it is virtually the same list of words. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Part of this is including your word list.  No, we don't need an external link to a full dictionary -- merely a few words that will illustrate the problem with your code.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what’s going wrong. You’re getting a `None` somewhere?

Comment: Forgot to add that I agree with @Prune, what matters is that we can understand the format of the data, we don't necessarily need the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

While we await some more details on the format of the input data, I thought I would come up with a basic solution using the words `words_alpha.txt` from github.com/dwyl/english-words.

I might produce a few different versions, I'll see if any are clearly superior to the others.

```py
import collections as colls
import operator as op
import random

words_dict = colls.defaultdict(list)

with open('../resources/words_alpha.txt') as words_file:
    for line in words_file:
        line_clean = line.strip()
        words_dict[len(line_clean)].append(line_clean)

# Python 3.7+, dictionaries are in insertion order.
words_list = list(words_dict.values())

pyramid_len = int(input("Enter the size of the pyramid: "))

for curr_words in words_list[:pyramid_len]:
    print(random.choice(curr_words))
```